# Cannot query dockerized MongoDB container from dockerized ASP.NET Core 3.1 container

Tags: mongodb, rest, docker, asp.net-core

I have a dockerized .net core container and am trying to query a MongoDB database. I have a REST API that is called to query the database from the .net core container. It seems as if I am able to establish a connection to the container when the instance of the service is created:

```
private readonly IMongoCollection<DbObject> _dbObjects;

public TaxService(IDbConfig dbConfig)
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine("got here: " + dbConfig.ConnectionString);
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient(dbConfig.ConnectionString);
    IMongoDatabase database = client.GetDatabase(dbConfig.DatabaseName);

    _dbObjects = database.GetCollection<DbObject>(dbConfig.SalesTaxCollectionName);
    Console.Out.WriteLine("db initialized");
}
```

Here is the `dbConfig` object:

```
"DbConfig": {
    "SalesTaxCollectionName": "ExampleCollection",
    "ConnectionString": "mongodb://mongo:27017",
    "DatabaseName": "ExampleDb"
}
```

It gets through this code, but when the database is actually queried, a `PlatformNotSupportedException` is thrown:

```
public DbObject GetByValue(string value)
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine("querying db");
    List<DbObject> matches = _dbObjects.Find(dbObject => dbObject.Value.Equals(value)).ToList();
    Console.Out.WriteLine("successfully queried"); // Does not reach this point

    if (matches.Any())
    {
        return matches.First();
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"No values matched");
    }
}
```

I have put the rest of the files in gists for convenience:

`docker-compose.yml`: https://gist.github.com/MinhazMurks/1fbb47afd360bbac48df45b1f0609e33

`Dockerfile`: https://gist.github.com/MinhazMurks/bb2b7f76d28894a81136d940b5997165

`InitExampleDb.js`: https://gist.github.com/MinhazMurks/9aae03daceee1e689c4e821419966f41

`Full-Log`: https://gist.github.com/MinhazMurks/0de9cd822fcf2930065527191127c83b

Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: are these services on the same network?

Comment: Yes, you can check out the docker-compose file to make sure, but they are, they are on the default network.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the following line in the host file:

(It is located here in case of Windows: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`)

```
127.0.0.1 mongo
```

After this try connect using RoboMongo. In the **Address** textbox insert `mongo` and try to connect to it.